# How to generate divs contiguos manner and not one bellow another using v-for

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have created a v-for loop that reads a JSON file to generate divs containing information about different products. While the divs are displaying correctly, the issue is that they are appearing one below the other instead of side by side. I've tried changing the CSS properties of the divs, such as the display property, but it hasn't worked. What do I need to modify to display the divs in a contiguous manner?

```html
<container class="newproducts">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12">
      <div class="llista">
        <div class="row">
          <div v-for="p in products" :key="p[0]" style="display: inline-block;">
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-l-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
              <div class="producte">
                <img :src="p[2]" class="productes" alt="producte 1" />
                <p>{{ p[1] }}</p>
                <div v-if="p[4] === 'new'" class="etiqueta">
                  <img src="resources/imgs/sign_new_offer.png" alt="new" srcset="" />
                </div>
                <div v-if="p[4] === 'offert'" class="etiqueta-offer">
                  <img src="resources/imgs/sign_offer.png" alt="offer" srcset="" />
                </div>
                <transition name="fade" appear>
                  <div class="modal-overlay" v-if="showModal" @click="showModal = false"></div>
                </transition>
                <transition name="slide" appear>
                  <div class="modal" v-if="showModal">
                    <button class="close" @click="showModal = false">X</button>
                    <img src="resources/imgs/detail_offer2.png" class="detailimg" alt="offer2">
                    <p>HACOA MASKING TAPE HOLDER</p>
                    <p class="price">22, 00€</p>
                    <div class="etiqueta-purchase">
                      <img src="resources/imgs/sign_new_offer_purchase.png" alt="newpurchase">
                    </div>
                    <input v-model="value" type="text" />
                    <p class="error">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
                    <button class="comprar" @click="addToCart">COMPRAR</button>
                  </div>
                </transition>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to merge the div that has the `v-for` with the one that has the col classes:

```html
<div
  v-for="p in products"
  :key="p[0]" 
  class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"
>
  ...
```

The way it is, you are creating children of a `row` that are not `col`s, each one of them containing a col. You could somewhat remedy that by making the divs flex, but you would still lose some formatting.

Have a look at snippet to see the difference:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.quad {
  min-width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<h6>Columns in row:</h6>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="quad"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="quad"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h6>Each columns in a div in row (this is what you do atm):</h6>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="quad"></div>
      </div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="quad"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<h6>Each columns in a div with d-flex in a row:</h6>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="quad"></div>
      </div>
      <div></div class="d-flex">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="quad"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also note that you are using `col-l-3`, but I think it has to be `col-lg-3`. If I remember correctly, Bootstrap will still use 3 slots because it is currently the setting on the next smaller screen (i.e. `col-sm-3`), but still, might be falling you your feet later on...